# laravel 5.1 Auth::check() 500 internal server error afterJWTAuth::attempt($credentials) login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1, jwt

I am creating login api in **laravel 5.1**.

I have created user authentication in controller

```
    try {

        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user

        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $response['error'] = 'true';
            $response['data'] = 'invalid_credentials';
            return response()->json($response);
        }

    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        $response['error'] = 'true';
        $response['data'] = 'could_not_create_token';
        return response()->json($response);
    }

    $response['error'] = 'false';

    $response['data'] = ['token'=>$token];
    return response()->json($response);
```

It is working, and successfully generating token.

but in this code before return, if check login `dd(Auth::check());`
It throws

> Status 500 Internal Server Error

Then here, How can I get user from database after successful login?

Comment: did you tried like this `dd(\Auth::check());` and also, switch on your debug mode in .env file

Comment: yes, still throwing same error

Comment: `Auth::check()` only checks that user is loggedin or not, if you want to get user attributes, try this `dd(\Auth::user()->id); or dd(\Auth::user()->name);` means your DB columns

Comment: yes, you are correct and I know it. I had tried dd(\Auth::user()->id) but it was throwing Status 500 Internal Server Error, so did check Auth::check() and it is throwing same error.Is there any other way to to do this?

Comment: after login, where you making `dd(Auth::user()->id)` ?

Comment: HTTP 500 errors are usually related to server configuration issues. Did you check Apache logs? (Assuming you are serving the site over Apache)

Comment: @Qazi I'm checking dd(Auth::user()->id)  after catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you done some Log in the function, check if you have the right permission on the relative log file. Log::info may throw the 500 server error.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know if Auth::check() will work by default in laravel 5.1 since JWTAUTH and Auth are two different interfaces.
so what i do is i have a function that i use to check and get the user details if the user is logged in.

```
 public function getAuthUser() {
    try {
        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            throw new Exception('user_not_found',404);
        }else{
            $data['user'] = $user;
        }

    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        throw new Exception('token_expired',$e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
        throw new Exception('invalid_token',$e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage(),403);
        throw new Exception('token_absent',$e->getStatusCode());
    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return $data;
}
```